# JPA load entities, but therein in a @OneToMany list, only load specific

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

**Situation:**
(using Payara Server)

I have multiple `Group`s, and each `Group` has their own specific set of `GroupMeeting`s.

These `GroupMeeting`s are tracked over multiple years. 
Each `Group` contains 100-10000 `GroupMeeting`s.
But usually only the current year's `GroupMeeting`s are queried and used.

**Problem:**

How can I load all `Group`s, but only load each `Group`'s `GroupMeeting` List for a specific interval, for example only the `GroupMeeting`s of 2019? Or, if need be, specific years or ranges, i.e. 2017-2021 etc?

If I simply run a "SELECT *", then with the `FetchType.LAZY`I will get empty an emtpy `List<GroupMeeting>`, but as soon as I access it somewhere in the code, all the items will be loaded.

**Question:**
Whats the best strategy, i.e. somewhat efficient but not overly convoluted?

- Is there an easy SQL/JPQL query that I can run with the classes below?
- Is there some structural change - especially in the annotations - needed?
- Should I consider Criteria API?
- Do I have to use two `List<GroupMeeting>`s, one with the commonly used meetings, the other with the 'old' meetings?

**Example:**
Here are the two classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Group {
    @Id //
    @GeneratedValue() //
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true) @JoinTable(name = "group_meetings") //
    private final List<GroupMeeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class GroupMeeting {
    @Id //
    @GeneratedValue() //
    private long id;

    private String  title;
    private Date    start;
    private Date    end;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate filters to achieve that, for instance:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="groupMeetingFilter",
        parameters={@ParamDef( name="fromDate", type="date"), @ParamDef(name="toDate", type="date")} )
public class Group {
    @Id //
    @GeneratedValue() //
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true) @JoinTable(name = "group_meetings")
    @Filter(
        name = "groupMeetingFilter",
        condition="start <= :fromDate and end >= :toDate"
    )
    private final List<GroupMeeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And you need to enable your filter somewhere in your application, just like this:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Filter filter = session.enableFilter("groupMeetingFilter");
//Define here the dates that you want
filter.setParameter("fromDate", new Date());
filter.setParameter("toDate", new Date());
```

You could go further with your research and make the filter global available, if you're using Spring for instance, is easier.

Comment: Ah man sorry I didnt accept this earlier. Still havent checked if it works for me, had no time since. But thanx a lot for answering this!